# Using a greater-than sign in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm working on an encryption assignment for my first CS class, and I'm trying to make this code work...  here's what I've got.

```
    public static void findE(int phiPQ) {

        int e = 0;

        for(e > 2; e < (phiPQ - 1);) {
            int larger = phiPQ;
            int smaller = e;
            int r = 1;
            r = larger / smaller;
            larger = smaller;
            smaller = r;

            if(larger  == 1) {
            break;
        }
        return; 
     }
```

Now the issue I'm having is that when I try to do "e > 2" in the for loop it does not work, and says that the assignment operator is invalid.  The assignment says that I'm supposed to use a for loop from e > 2 to e < (phiPQ - 1).  How is this possible without something like a while loop?  I tried that as well and couldn't get the return statement to work.  Please help!

Comment: for(e > 2; e < (phiPQ - 1);); <-- last ; make it a empty loop

Comment: Please *take care* when fixing up original code mistakes. Some are *very crucial* to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has "fixed" some of the issues discussed below. YMMV.

---

There are several critical problems with the code. The combination of syntax and/or semantic errors may compound upon each other. *First* start by fixing the blatant syntax errors.

#### 1. The for syntax is wrong.

The first "part" of a [`for` loop statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) must be an *initialization* statement (read: "assignment"). It *cannot* be an arbitrary expression. The syntax is `for(initialization; termination; increment) statement` - see the link for more details.

I expect the code should be:

```
for(/* At the start, LET e = 2 */
    e = 2 ;
    /* Terminate when this is false. */
    e < (phiPQ - 1) ;
    /* no increment */) ..
```

Or:

```
for(e = 2; e < (phiPQ - 1) ;) ..
```

(Or, assign 2 to `e` above the for-loop and provide an *empty* initialization statement.)

#### 2. As identified by a comment is the code is equivalent to:

```
// This is a loop with AN EMPTY STATEMENT FOR A BODY due to the
// immediately trailing semicolon.
// Even when this loop is corrected per above, the condition will never
// change state due to lack of increment and it will "loop forever".
for(e > 2; e < (phiPQ - 1);) ;

// This is a new block, that does NOT BELONG to the loop above.
{
    int larger = phiPQ;
    int smaller = e;
    int r = 1;
    r = larger / smaller;
    larger = smaller;
    smaller = r;
}
```

To fix this, remove the `;` immediately following the `for` statement.

#### 3. The loop never changes state.

The termination condition is dependent upon `e` and `phiPQ`. However, these variables are *never* changed and so the loop will either never loop or never terminate normally.

Review the loop termination conditions and state advancement.

#### 4. `break` is used *outside* of the for statement.

While #3 asserts that the code never terminates, it may be the case that the `if` statement containing the `break` (which is *incorrectly* located outside of a looping construct and will result in a syntax error) is meant to terminate the loop. If this is the case, then it should be *inside* the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (int e = 0; e > 2 && e < (phiPQ - 1);)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Code in your for loop body will not run because  0 never great than  2.

Comment: This works, but then it says that the break statement is outside of a loop or switch.  I tried moving my } around and nothing works without messing up the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

For loop :

```
for(int e = 3; e < (phiPQ - 1); e++){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because the first expression in a `for-loop` is used for initialisation. The second expression is then your termination condition; when the termination condition evaluates to `false`, the loop will end. e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {}
```

This loop will iterate through the body `numIterations` times.

You will therefore want to more fully define the iteration space of your loop in the second expression, or perform assignment of `e` through the first expression.

For more information, refer to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for `for-loop`s.